# rCharts nplot piechart, turn off legend/toggle buttons

Tags: r, rcharts

Given:

```
df <- data.frame(var = letters[1:26], count = sample(1:300, 26),
                 label = sample(toupper(letters[1:5]), 26, replace = T))
library(rCharts)

p4 <- nPlot(count ~ var, data = df, type = 'pieChart',
            width = 500, height=500)
p4$chart(tooltipContent = "#! function(x, y){ 
  return 'Type: ' + x + '<br>Count: ' + y
} !#")
p4
```

Can I turn off/remove the legend at the top? Or move it from the top to the left/right?

Comment: Nevermind: `p4$chart(showLegend = FALSE)` does the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll post my own answer so this question is closed.

```
p4$chart(showLegend = FALSE)
```